# display random list item, by reloading only one div

Tags: javascript

I am working on a page wherein a single `<li>` is displayed. When a button is pressed, the page reloads and randomly displays another `<li>`. I've gotten achieved this with the following:

```
this.randomtip = function(){
    var length = $("#tips li").length;
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
    $("#tips li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
```

and...

```
<a href="#" class="myButton" onClick="location.reload();">
```

When the button reloads the page several elements jump and fall back into place. I've tried holding these elements in divs with fixed heights. Is a way to only reload this one div to avoid the jumping?

Comment: do you actually have to reload the page? why not just hide and show the list items?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the page just use the click event on the button to hide the tips and show a random one:

```
$(function(){
    var $tips = $("#tips li");
    $('.myButton').click(function(){
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*$tips.length);
        $tips.hide().eq(rand).show();
        return false;
    }).triggerHandler('click'); //Trigger event on page load
});
```

Here's a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/WBYr2/)**